# How to config to get good splash screen with Ascii Art or maybe a picture like Lunarvim and Spacevim?

Tags: original-vim, lunarvim

I see in Lunarvim and Spacevim have the same appearance when is opened.

Did they use the same plugin or have special configuration?

Currently, I'm using Vim8.2.

You can help me by showing your experiences with splash screen. Thanks a lot.

[image: j]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the splash screen? Lunarvim uses [dashboard-nvim](https://github.com/glepnir/dashboard-nvim), which you can pull in on its own and you can customize it too... (I'm sure SpaceVim uses a plug-in for that too, I bet it's a different plug-in though.) Or do you mean something else? Like color scheme, etc.?

Comment: Oh, I don't know the term "splash screen". I think Spacevim use sth like [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify#installation-and-documentation)

Comment: I think SpaceVim uses [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify).

Comment: So is that what you're looking for? Or was it something else? Should I write an answer mentioning these two plug-ins? If it's something else that you're after, would you please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you're looking for?

Comment: I really appreciate if you share your configs or your experiences with 2 plugin.

Comment: I don't use either of them, so... Still not sure what's your objective here... If you know about the plug-ins, so then what's the "good appearance" that you're after? Do you mean the logos using ASCII Art? Do you want to produce a logo for a different name or something like that? Please [edit] the question with more details of what it is that you actually want.

Comment: "Please share your configuration" is too broad (there is no best answer). "Experience" is similarly too broad or opinion-based. This site focuses on objective Q&A (see https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). There is also [chat] to simply chat.

Comment: Ok, I understood

Answer (score 2):

There are plug-ins that can be used to show a menu of useful options and include a splash screen that you can customize when Vim or NeoVim is started without opening any files from the command line.

LunarVim uses [dashboard-nvim](https://github.com/glepnir/dashboard-nvim) for that, and SpaceVim uses [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify), so you could either pick up one of these two, or search for similar plug-ins in case you're not fully satisfied with these.

Regarding producing an ASCII Art banner with custom text, there are many tools around that can convert text or images to ASCII Arg, just [search for "ascii art generator"](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=ascii+art+generator) and you'll find many links, many of them are online tools, that can be used to produce ASCII Art for you. It's hard to recommend one of them, since they mostly support different styles of "ASCII Art Fonts", so you should experiment with them to see which one you'd like.

---

Vim/NeoVim can also be used to tweak ASCII Art, particularly if you already have something to start with and would like to make a few small tweaks for the most part.

For example, you can use the [`R`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#R) command to replace characters without changing the rest of the line, which is useful to edit something on the left side without affecting the right side of a line.

[Visual block mode](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#visual-block) can be very useful to select rectangles of text and copy, duplicate, overwrite, or delete them.

Also take a look at the [`'virtualedit'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27) setting, you most likely want to use `set virtualedit=all` while editing something like ASCII Art, that will allow you to navigate past the end of lines and insert text or drawing characters wherever you like.